# Mayor issue at startup

Tags: startup, postgresql, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux) in a MSI MS-7788 desktop machine (Intel i5 at 3 GHz, 8 GB RAM, 1TB HDD).

My little daughter was used this and... I don't know what she did!

When I restarted on the PC... The device starts all the startup process up... A time when some "Failure" status related with some PostgreSQL and then.. The system, is starting to tells me:

"Started Session Cxxx of user gdm.xx/UID 0"

x = consecutive numbers.

This is repeated a lot of times!

It reaches a counting up to "C185", or more, and then shows me the following text:

"Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...pleted startup"

And that's all!!!

Nothing more, nothing less. That is all the PC does.

What is wrong here?

How can I fix it?

How can I avoid this happens again?

Comment: I don't now if it is an "official" solution (I think, no), but... It worked for me! I used the Ubuntu Studio 18.04 Installation DVD to have access to my HDDs. I checked that the main partition had 0 byte free! So... I erased some not important data (I don't agree that Ubuntu put in this partition some folders like: Download, Documents, Music, etc) and moved other data to another partitions. I got more than 25 GB free in that device. I restarted the machine and... Voila! All is working so fine, again!

Comment: But... I think something is using space in that partition (not the data I erased or moved) and I really want to know what is and where it is! BTW: I also uninstalled the PostgreSQL software because I don't know for what is and I don't want to have this issue again, so... Just in case...